# Select second Value

Tags: php, select

I have this select in my form:

```
<select id="select" name="gametype" onchange="myFunction(event)">
  <option disabled selected value>Please Select Game Type</option>
  <option value="28,000" >HD 6 Cameras saterday</option>
  <option value="30,000" >HD 6 Cameras</option>
  <option value="50,0000">HD 7 Cameras saterday</option>
  <option value="32,0000">HD 7 Cameras</option>
  <option value="45,000" >4k 7 Cameras saterday</option>
  <option value="32,000" >4k 7 Cameras</option>
</select>
```

I am passing the value of the option in `$_POST`. How can I also pass the text of the option? For example, if the value is "28,800" I also want to pass "HD 6 Cameras saterday."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're handling the other components of this form, but I removed the onchange attribute binding from the select element and just used jquery to set the text displayed to the user as a hidden variable.

```html
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['gametype'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "<hr/>";
  }
 ?>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <form class="myForm" method="post">
    <!--this is empty and stays that way until you submit it-->
    <input type="hidden" name="gametype_desc" class="gametype_desc" value="" />
    <select id="select" class="selGameType" name="gametype">
      <option disabled selected value>Please Select Game Type</option>
      <option value="28,000" >HD 6 Cameras saterday</option>
      <option value="30,000" >HD 6 Cameras</option>
      <option value="50,0000">HD 7 Cameras saterday</option>
      <option value="32,0000">HD 7 Cameras</option>
      <option value="45,000" >4k 7 Cameras saterday</option>
      <option value="32,000" >4k 7 Cameras</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("select.selGameType").change(function(){
        //uncomment to log the value in the console
        //console.log($(this).children(":selected").text());
        //uncomment to log the value in the console
        //console.log($(this).val());
        //get the text of the currently selected option
        selText = $(this).children(":selected").text();
        //we set the value of the hidden variable, so that the text (not value) is passed as a separate post var
        $("input.gametype_desc").val(selText);

        //now you might submit it, or whatever your next step is...
        $("form.myForm").submit();
      })
    })

  </script>
```